# JavaFX Slider - changeListener not triggered when arrow-buttton-press (->) moves slider

Tags: javafx, slider

My *valueChangingProperty Listener* catches only events caused by mouse (drag slider with mouse or click mouse somewhere inside the slider). It soes not respond to slider moving (and therefore its value changing) when I press arrow button (->), though I see that it causes the slider to move.

```
MyController.java

private Slider playRewindSlider;

playRewindSlider.valueChangingProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {

        boolean finishedDragging = !(Boolean) observable.getValue();
        
        if (finishedDragging) {
            // logic triggered ONCE after slider moving finished
        }
    }           
});
```

How to additionally catch changing slider with arrow (->) ?

P.S. I saw many posts on SO concerning slider, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `valueChanging` property indicates if the slider is *in the process* of being changed (typically this means the user is dragging the slider thumb). This won't happen if the user performs a single action that changes the value (because the value changes, but the slider is never in a state of the value *still* changing).

Typically, you want to respond to the `value` itself changing:

```
playRewindSlider.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    // process newValue
});
```

The purpose of the `valueChanging` property is to avoid performing lots of updates as the user drags the thumb. So you can restrict to updating only when the change is complete by checking that property in the listener for `value`:

```
playRewindSlider.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (! playRewindSlider.isValueChanging()) {
        // process newValue
    }
});
```

Note that this won't get triggered by dragging the thumb with the mouse (because the value changes, but `valueChanging` doesn't get set to false until *after* the final change). So you need to include a second listener (your original `valueChanging` listener):

```
playRewindSlider.valueChangingProperty().addListener((obs, wasChanging, isNowChanging) -> {
    if (! isNowChanging) {
        double newValue = playRewindSlider.getValue();
        // process newValue
    }
});
```

You can reduce the code by creating a single listener which you add to both properties:

```
ChangeListener<Object> sliderListener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (! playRewindSlider.isValueChanging()) {
        double newValue = playRewindSlider.getValue();
        // process newValue
    }
};
playRewindSlider.valueProperty().addListener(sliderListener);
playRewindSlider.valueChangingProperty().addListener(sliderListener);
```

Here's a complete example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Slider slider = new Slider();
        
        ChangeListener<Object> listener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (! slider.isValueChanging()) {
                processSliderChange(slider.getValue());
            }
        };
        slider.valueProperty().addListener(listener);
        slider.valueChangingProperty().addListener(listener);
        
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(slider);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    private void processSliderChange(double value) {
        System.out.printf("%.2f%n", value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

---

One other option here is to do some clever work with a binding, which is invalidated if either the slider's `valueProperty` or `valueChangingProperty` change, but only if `valueChangingProperty` is false:

```
    DoubleBinding sliderValue = new DoubleBinding() {
        
        {
            InvalidationListener l = obs -> {
                if (! playRewindSlider.isValueChanging()) invalidate();
            };
            playRewindSlider.valueProperty().addListener(l);
            playRewindSlider.valueChangingProperty().addListener(l);
        }

        @Override
        protected double computeValue() {
            return playRewindSlider.getValue();
        }
        
    };
```

and then

```
sliderValue.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    // process newValue
});
```

is triggered exactly when you need.

Here's the same example using this technique:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Slider slider = new Slider();
        
        DoubleBinding sliderValue = new DoubleBinding() {
            
            {
                InvalidationListener l = obs -> {
                    if (! slider.isValueChanging()) invalidate();
                };
                slider.valueProperty().addListener(l);
                slider.valueChangingProperty().addListener(l);
            }

            @Override
            protected double computeValue() {
                return slider.getValue();
            }
            
        };

        sliderValue.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
            processSliderChange(newValue.doubleValue()));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(slider);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    private void processSliderChange(double value) {
        System.out.printf("%.2f%n", value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

> How to additionally catch changing slider with arrow (->) ?

If you want to catch the specific event you can add an event filter like this:

```
scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
    if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT && slider.isFocused()) {
        System.out.println("Value changed because of key right pressed on slider").
    }
});
```

Comment: But the OP wants the functionality that this code disables: "How to additionally catch changing slider with arrow?"

Comment: Just in case he wants the specific event (->).

Comment: Exactly. They *do* want that event to be captured. Your code disables that event entirely. Plus, there are other circumstances where the slider's value can be changed without the `valueChangingProperty()` ever changing (left arrow, or mouse click on the track, etc.), so this doesn't solve the underlying problem.

Comment: I just posted my answer after yours as an addition just in case he wants to know how to track that specific right key press event on the slider.